# How do I generate a rolling 3-day sum of my data using SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a simple table called `values`:

```
ID   day         value
 1   2023-09-21     37
 2   2023-09-21     14
 3   2023-09-22     42
 4   2023-09-23      9
 5   2023-09-23     10
 6   2023-09-23     11
 7   2023-09-24     14
 8   2023-09-24     16
 9   2023-09-25      6
10   2023-09-25      4
11   2023-09-26     17
12   2023-09-27     22
13   2023-09-28     31
14   2023-09-28      9
```

I'd like to generate a rolling 3-day sum, ie. total for past 3 days, for each day.

So the end result would be:

```
day         total
2023-09-21     51  (21st = 37+14)
2023-09-22     93  (21st + 42)
2023-09-23    123  (21st + 22nd + (9+10+11))
2023-09-24    102  (22nd + 23rd + (14+16))
2023-09-25     70  (23rd + 24th + (6+4))
2023-09-26     57  (24th + 25th + 17)
2023-09-27     49  (25th + 26th + 22)
2023-09-28     79  (26th + 27th + (31+9))
```

I can calculate the total per day easily enough, ie.

```
SELECT day, sum(value) as daily_total
FROM values
GROUP by day
ORDER BY day
```

which gives me:

```
day   daily_total
2023-09-21     51
2023-09-22     42
2023-09-23     30
2023-09-24     30
2023-09-25     10
2023-09-26     17
2023-09-27     22
2023-09-28     40
```

I'm using a recent version of PostgreSQL and I cannot get a moving/running total no matter what I try. I've had a go at replicating examples that use window functions and partition by ranges. I'm sure it's going to be simple, however it's defeating me at the moment.

Comment: This question was closed as a duplicate and this is probably reasonable. I found the answer below worked and it seems to me to be a much simpler approach than the answer in the linked post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT a.day,
       SUM(a.value) OVER (
           ORDER BY a.day
           ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND
               CURRENT ROW
           ) AS total
FROM (SELECT day, SUM(value) AS value
      FROM values
      GROUP BY day) AS a
ORDER BY a.day;
```

you can try this query